# Error: "expected class name"

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I've searched through the other "expected Class Name" error questions on here, but they all "...before '{' token," or "...before ';'".

The solution was to include the right file, but my file is including the .h file that included the inherited class.

```
#include "BinaryNode.h"
#include "bst.h"

template <class T>
class SOBTree: public BinarySearchTree { //Expected Class Name
public:
    void insert( const T& x );
    void remove( const T& x );
    int reportComparisonCount();
    double reportCPUTime();


private:
    void insert( const T & x, BinaryNode<T> * & t );
    void RotateRight(BinaryNode<T> * & root );
    void RotateLeft(BinaryNode<T> * & root );
    BinaryNode<T> *root;

};
```

The inherited class is defined in bst.h, so I have no other files to include in the project.

Sorry for the easy question, I just don't know why the error is happening.

Comment: What files do each of those headers include?  Is it possible you have a circular set of includes?

Comment: Can't say anything without viewing bst.h. And please state which compiler you are using.

Comment: Unrelated: your class appears to violate the rule of three/five.

Comment: I don;t know what the rule of three five is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
class SOBTree: public BinarySearchTree
```

to

```
class SOBTree: public BinarySearchTree<T>
```

..as BinarySearchTree, is(definitely) a template too.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that BinarySearchTree is also a template, and you need to derive from `BinarySearchTree<T>`?

Otherwise it's obvious that BinarySearchTree was never defined. The cause of that might be conflicting header guards in your header files.